# Automatically truncating long output in bash

Tags: bash

Is it possible to automatically truncate long output in bash?

Ideally I would like to define a limit, say MAXLINES, and automatically apply `tail -n $MAXLINES` to every command that outputs more than MAXLINES lines to the terminal (but not in other contexts, e.g. pipes, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be done using `PROMPT_COMMAND`

```
MAXLINES=10
tmp_out=/tmp/$$.output
PROMPT_COMMAND='touch "$tmp_out"; tail -n "$MAXLINES" "$tmp_out" >/dev/stdin; exec >"$tmp_out"'
```

How it works

- `tmp_out=/tmp/$$.output` temporary file used to store output of command
- `touch "$tmp_out"` : create empty file if doesn't exist so that tail command doesn't fail at first call
- `tail -n "$MAXLINE" "$tmp" > /dev/stdin` : show first maxlines of output
- `exec > "$tmp_out"` : clear temporary file and redirects current process output (file descriptor 1) to this file, in case stderr can also be redirected to another file to be truncated (for example `2> "$tmp_err"`).

To run a command without redirection

```
exec >/dev/stdin; ... the command
```

or (space after `{` is important)

```
{ the command;}>/dev/stdin
```

To retrieve inital settings

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND; exec >/dev/stdin
```

Comment: You might first want to open a new shell with `bash`. When you want normal output, you can `exit`.

Comment: @Nahuel: very nice. However, when you say `ls -la | less`, for example, long output gets also truncated, since less doesn’t know it’s supposed to output to a terminal. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: indeed because the tail is done after the command finishes in prompt so program that work with tty can't work interactively to restore output following can be done `exec >/dev/stdin ; ls -la | less`

Comment: note also that some program like `ls` behaves differently when output is a tty or a file for example with escape sequence, compare `touch  ''$'\033''[31mhello'$'\033''[0m'` and `ls *hello*` and `ls *hello* >/dev/stdin` , also `ls -a` in a tty will display file names in columns whereas in a file will display one file by line like `ls -a1`